# PF2E Eidolon Grappling Capabilities?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

As far as I know, there is no way for an Eidolon to obtain the "Grapple" trait on one of their attacks.

A level one Summoner is granted an Eidolon and has the ability to choose from one of the following for their primary form of attack

- 1d8 damage (disarm, nonlethal, shove, or trip)
- 1d6 damage (fatal d10)
- 1d6 damage (forceful and sweep)
- 1d6 damage (deadly d8 and finesse)

Along with these attacks, the Eidolon is also granted a single option for a secondary attack:

- 1d6 damage (agile and finesse).

At level twelve the summoner can pick up a Class Feat called "Grasping Limbs" which reads: "**Your eidolon grabs enemies. Choose one of the eidolon's unarmed attacks with the grapple trait. It gains the Grab action (Bestiary 343) on that unarmed attack.**

*How would a Summoner/Eidolon be able to make use of the Class Feature "Grasping Limbs" if they are unable to acquire an attack with the "Grapple" trait?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Advanced Weaponry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2886) Feat (level 1) allows you to give your Eidolon's primary melee attack the choice of one of the following traits: disarm, grapple, nonlethal, shove, trip, or versatile bludgeoning, piercing, or slashing.